# Archive posts on showing current page instead of archive

Tags: blog-page, archive-template

I have tried to create an index page of all my blogs on a menu link: Blog

I created a new page: Blog (id:267)

I copied archive.php to page-267.php

Yet, when I view this page, it only shows one result - the Blog Page - why is it not listing all blogs in the archive like the archive page should?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

A template with a standard loop just outputs the contents of the main query, which is based on the requested URL. WordPress loads specific templates based on the results of the main query, but the template itself isn't otherwise connected to what the main query contains, that all happens before the template is loaded.

If you want to show content in a page aside from what is generated by the main query, you have to query for it yourself. See [`WP_Query` in Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) for everything you need to know about creating queries in WordPress.

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
        echo '</ul>';
} else {
    // no posts found
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
```